# Express.js can't display images from directory 'images' with express.static

Tags: express

Below is my `index.js` file where I set up port 3000 on localhost to serve `index.html`.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// trying to make this directory public
app.use(express.static('images'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html'));

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

`index.html` calls `img` assets, like this:

```
<body>
    <h1>hello</h1>
    <img src="images/favicon512.png" />
</body>
```

The image doesn't show in the browser. I figured `app.use(express.static('images'));` would expose everything within directory `images` to be seen publicly.

My app is structured like this:

```
index.js
index.html
images/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with :

```
<img src="/favicon512.png" />
```

Comment: Interesting. Not sure I completely understand what's going on here. It's like `express.static()` is bringing everything from that file path into the current directory or something? Anyway, thanks. I'll mark this when it lets me.

Comment: As you understand ;)